# WCF LocalChannel, call a service within a service, same app, same machine

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to find an example but no luck, just the following

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/local-channel

Any who, I am trying to:

```
Service1.Method(){
  Service2.Method()
}
```

Both Services live in the same application/domain/machine

Thanks!
eVaz

Comment: Appreciate if you can edit the post by updating what you are trying to create, where you are facing problem along with clear piece of code that you had tried.

Comment: This example has been deleted. You can talk about what function you want to achieve and what problems you have encountered. I can share this example by way of code.